# Can i make a Bridge to get internet from the wifi on my laptop?

Tags: internet

Can i make a bridge to get internet from wifi on my laptop to my desktop PC
with Ethernet cable?

yes?
How?

My laptop is running Win7 and my desktop Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu you are using ? I have not setup one by myself but I found an [official help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge) about setting up bridge for Ubuntu which is good till version 12.04 (but they say it should work for later versions too).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.10?
Thanks!
i hope this will work!